# How do I implement single authentication in a RESTful app?

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication

I can't seem to grasp how authentication works for REST using Zend Framework. I want the user to be able to login once and then allow him to access any area of the site depending on his user level. We have a working non-REST login code, I just basically copied it and placed in `postAction()` method of the `Api_LoginController` class.

```
class Api_LoginController extends REST_Controller
{
    public function postAction() {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $form    = new Application_Form_LoginForm;

        if ($request->isPost()) {
            if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
                $email     = $form->getValue('email');
                $password  = $form->getValue('password');

                $user = Application_Model_UserModel::getUserByEmail($email);
                if ( $user && $user->login($password)) {
                        echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'message' => 'Logged in.'));
                } else {
                       echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message' => 'Login failed.'));
                }
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

How do I go from here? Should Zend(1.11) be able to identify the user in the subsequent access? Right now, it appears it can't identify the same user after login.

Comment: you can throw the auth code inside `init`

Comment: @DevZer0: Could you make it a proper answer please. I'm a noob.

Comment: every controller has a initialize method called init, you can use that to handle authorization on each request.

Comment: @DevZero: I'm sorry, so you are saying persistent connection is not possible with REST? Or in other words, the client would have to send the username and password each time he makes a request?

Comment: Presistent connections in HTTP is maintained via session cookies. DO you have better ideas

Comment: @DevZer0 Is that a Yes or No? I have no idea which is why I'm asking here in the first place :-) Did you mean I would have to authenticate the user in each request?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38703/discussion-between-rade-and-devzer0)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to provide authentication in a REST application using Zend.

This is roughly the idea behind it:

- A User logs in using his username/password
- In your Application you validate the login credentials
- Using these credentials you can generate an unique token, similar to a session token in a normal application
- You send back the identification token to the User
- Each subsequent request the User has to provide his token, as proof he's logged in
- Your Application will validate this token and do the required action

Zend contains a lot of this stuff already, with a bit of searching you'll find a lot of functionality that might provide some of these points and make them fit in your application.